# Sorting information and processing output with variables in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, sed, scripting

I've received some helpful responses in the past and am hoping you can all help me out.  I came across some weird behavior that I can't quite nail down.  I'm processing configuration files for Cisco switches and want to generate output that lists the VLAN IP Addresses in a format that would show:

Vlan1: 172.31.200.1 255.255.255.0

Vlan10: 172.40.220.1 255.255.255.0

The "Vlan" would be captured in a variable and the IP/Mask is extracted using "sed" and it works for the most part.  Occasionally though it refuses to populate the "vlan" variable even though it appears to work great for other configs.

If there's only one VLAN it just handles that one, if there's more than one it handles the additional ones.  If the user selects (-v) it includes VLAN1 on the list there are multiple VLANs configured (otherwise it ignores VLAN1).

This input file appears broken (Filename 1.cfg):

```
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.29.96.100 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 172.29.96.1
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
```

This input file works fine (Filename 2.cfg):

```
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.31.200.111 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 172.31.200.1
ip http server
ip http secure-server
```

The output that I get is this:

[image]

Notice how the first one fails to include the "Vlan1" reference?

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f getlan.log ];
then
    rm getlan.log
fi

TempFile=getlan.log
verbose=0

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
    -v)
    verbose=1
    shift
    ;;
    #*)
    #exit
    #shift
    #;;
esac
done

#Start Processing all files
files=$( ls net )
for i in $files; do

    #########################################################
    # Collect Configured VLAN Interfaces and IP Information #
    #########################################################

    echo "--------  Configured VLAN Interfaces  --------" >> ~/$TempFile
    echo "" >> ~/$TempFile

    if [ `grep "^interface Vlan" ~/net/$i | awk '{ print $2 }' | wc -l` -gt 1 ];
    then
        for g in `grep "^interface Vlan" ~/net/$i | awk '{ print $2 }'`;
        do
            if [ $g == "Vlan1" ];
            then
                if [ $verbose -gt 0 ];
                then
                    echo "$g": `sed -n '/^interface '$g'/,/!/p' ~/net/$i | head -n 5 | grep -i "ip address" | awk '{ print $3, $4 }'` >> ~/$TempFile
                fi  
            else
                echo "$g": `sed -n '/^interface '$g'/,/^!/p' ~/net/$i | grep -i "ip address" | awk '{ print $3, $4 }'` >> ~/$TempFile
            fi
        done
        echo "" >> ~/$TempFile
    else
        vlanid=`grep "^interface Vlan" ~/net/$i | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        echo $vlanid: `sed -n '/^interface 'Vlan'/,/^!/p' ~/net/$i | grep -i "address" | awk '{ print $3, $4 }'` >> ~/$TempFile
        echo "" >> ~/$TempFile
    fi
done
```

It would be really great if this was more consistent. Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The sample includes both... the desired output is to have the line include the Vlan (Vlan1, Vlan10, etc) followed by the IP and Mask.  The second instance is correct.  In the first instance it only shows the IP/Mask.

Also my input files are shown above in the original description.

Comment: In general, `grep ... | awk '{foo}'` can be replaced with `awk '/.../ { foo }'`. I would also generally tend to be getting rid of all the `sed`/`head`/`awk`/etc. miscellany in favor of using a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to parse your file, which will both be more efficient and runtime and have less incidental complexity (fewer moving parts).

Comment: Consider also running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. Quoting rules in bash are perhaps inverse of what you expect coming from other languages -- in `[ "$g" = Vlan1 ]`, for example, it's the expansion of the variable that needs to be quoted for your code to behave reliably when reading empty strings or other unusual file contents, *not* the constant string.

Answer (score 0):

A best-practices approach might look more like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
interface_re='^[[:space:]]*interface[[:space:]]+(.*)'
ip_re='^[[:space:]]*ip address (.*)'

process_file() {
  local line interface

  interface=
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $interface_re ]]; then
      interface=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      continue
    fi
    if [[ $interface ]] && [[ $line =~ $ip_re ]]; then
      echo "${interface}: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
  done
}

for file in net/*; do
  process_file <"$file"
done
```

---

This can be tested as follows:

```
process_file <<'EOF'
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.29.96.100 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 172.29.96.1
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.31.200.111 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 172.31.200.1
ip http server
ip http secure-server
EOF
```

...which correctly identifies the `ip address` lines from both `interface` blocks, emitting:

```
Vlan1: 172.29.96.100 255.255.255.0
Vlan1: 172.31.200.111 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm sure my coding is not up to spec with best practices and it's always good to see other ways to do things.

I tried your code and received the same results though.  The first entry still fails to include the Vlan identifier.  What's odd though, use my code above and add an echo statement to echo the $vlanid it echoes successfully, but the line to create the vlan:ip mask still fails.  That's odd, because it shows it is successfully setting the variable. Additionally, it works on the other instance.

Comment: Use `set -x` to enable logging. I wouldn't be surprised if there are hidden characters in the input.

Comment: Keep in mind, by the way -- you can take my code in this answer over to http://ideone.com/ and see it working there. Right now, I **can't** see it failing, anywhere. If you built a MCVE for the problem someone else could use to see the code fail with no changes whatsoever (no needing to `mkdir net` and create files in it, just copy-and-paste -- exactly as you can copy-and-paste from this answer with no changes necessary to test it), that would do a lot of good.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/z7jq3o for such a working example. If you click the `fork` button and change the input until it fails, having that would put someone in a much better position to help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I was going through the input files as well.  I've noticed that there are extra characters occassionally and it causes me grief.  Perl has the "chomp" feature and there isn't a simple equivalent in Bash to remove hidden things.

In 'vi' there is an character, but deleting it doesn't appear to change the behavior.  Enabling the '-x' does confirm it is my problem.  It registers the first "Vlan1" as "Vlan1\r"

Comment: I was able to resolve this by adding **| tr -d '\r\** to the end of the lines setting the $vlanid and $g variables.  This removes the extra character.

Comment: After `read -r line`, you could add `line=${line%$'\r'}` to trim those as well.